# Record all influential factors even at high n?

Tags: sample-size, causality, glmm

my task is to evaluate the effect of a fish predator (otter) on fish abundance in natural waterbodies. While otters are found in one part of the country already in good abundances, a quick expansion of the range is expected soon across the entire region. Ideally, I would want to monitor the fish stocks currently unaffected by otters in a standardized way with electrofishing across many different waterbodies, concomitantly monitor the otter presence and do this for a couple of years until otters have arrived in all (or most) waterbodies. so I’d have nice before - after data and maybe even controls. However, financial constraints do not allow for this kind of data.

Instead, I thought of recruiting anglers to provide catch and effort data in different parts of the country. Ideally, I would have let’s say 100 individual anglers from different locations providing the following data:
Name, Waterbody, Date, Presence of Otters, Hours fished, Number of fish captured.
I could then apply a GLMM like the following:
Number of fish captured ~ Presence of Otters + offset(Hours fished) + (1|Waterbody) + (1|Date) + (1|Name)
However, I am not accounting for the fact that there are many other factors affecting catch per effort, my proxy for abundance: In some waterbodies stocking of fish takes place at varying quantities each year. Then there may be other predators affecting fish abundance. Floods or heat waves can negatively affect fish abundance. While I won’t be able to record all these metrics for all waterbodies.

My question is the following:
Is it appropriate to assume that as long as the number of waterbodies investigated is high (let’s say maybe n = 50) and there is no reason to assume that any of the other variables affecting fish abundance (other predators, heat, floods, stocking…) systematically co-varies with the presence of otters that it may not be necessary to record them and still be able to draw conclusions on the effect of otters alone?

I would appreciate feedback to my question a lot

Phil

Answer (score 1):

This is a cool use-case of applied causal inference!

To answer your question directly: If there is no confounding and you have sufficient samples, causal inference is definitely a lot easier and you can focus entirely on estimating the parameters. (Edit: note that the number of samples doesn't affect the presence of confounding.)

However, I suspect the real challenge lies in arguing whether that's indeed the case. Why wouldn't something like the presence of other predators act as a potential confounder? And could there be selection bias on the waterbodys frequented by anglers?

A typical approach to sidestep confounding is [instrumental variable regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variables_estimation), perhaps that's something to consider in your case.

Comment: (+1) Also I don't see why high N would eliminate omitted variable bias, unfortunately.